# Face detection through Raspberry pi using java and usb web camera

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to pass an algorithm to make my pi eligible to capture images of human faces continuously in stream. For that my requirement is to use java for algorithm. And web cam attached to take images.

I have installed OS on raspberry and it works fine.  I have installed java and camera is running. But since i want it to detect images so i m not able to find
an algorithm and steps that i can use to detect images. Can anyone help?